# The directional derivative and the gradient

Tags: calculus

When calculating the directional derivative of $f\left( x,y \right) =\left( x+y \right) \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } } $ at point $\left( 0,0 \right) $ in the direction of the unit vector ${ e }_{ 1 }=\left( 1,0 \right) $ using the formula ${ D }_{ { e }_{ 1 } }f\left( 0,0 \right) =\nabla f\left( 0,0 \right) .{ e }_{ 1 }$ does not exist, because $\frac { \partial f\left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \partial x }$ and $\frac { \partial f\left( 0,0 \right)  }{ \partial y } $ evaluated at that point does not exist. However, using the definition of a directional derivative, its value is zero. Similarly it results in the direction of the unit vector ${ e }_{ 2 }=\left( 0,1 \right) $. I can not find the reason for it. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the definition of $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ you know?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the product rule to find that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{(x+y)x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$ and then concluding that this partial derivative doesn't exist at $(x,y)=(0,0)?$ This is a mistake, but it is very common, and you shouldn't feel bad. The fact is that the product rule states:

> If $f$ and $g$ are **both differentiable** at $x_0$, then $h=f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $h'(x_0)=f'(x_0)g(x_0)+f(x_0)g'(x_0)$.

The subtlety, which I bolded, is that both functions in the product need to be differentiable, which is not the case here. So since you cannot use the product rule, use the limit definition of the derivative to find the gradient.